# Is it possible to print a table row by row in Smarty (PHP template engine)?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, smarty, template-engine

I just installed Smarty (a PHP template engine) and I am refactoring my code to try to get dynamic HTML tables to work. I looked at the documentation and it appears that it wants me to generate a giant array in PHP before I pass my variables to Smarty. This is one of their examples:

```
// assign an associative array of data
$smarty->assign('users', array(
array('name' => 'bob', 'phone' => '555-3425'),
array('name' => 'jim', 'phone' => '555-4364'),
array('name' => 'joe', 'phone' => '555-3422'),
array('name' => 'jerry', 'phone' => '555-4973'),
array('name' => 'fred', 'phone' => '555-3235')
));
```

To output something like...

```
<table>
{foreach $users as $user}
{strip}
   <tr bgcolor="{cycle values="#aaaaaa,#bbbbbb"}">
      <td>{$user.name}</td>
      <td>{$user.phone}</td>
   </tr>
{/strip}
{/foreach}
</table>
```

.

```
<table>
<tr bgcolor="#aaaaaa"><td>bob</td><td>555-3425</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#bbbbbb"><td>jim</td><td>555-4364</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#aaaaaa"><td>joe</td><td>555-3422</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#bbbbbb"><td>jerry</td><td>555-4973</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#aaaaaa"><td>fred</td><td>555-3235</td></tr>
</table>
```

That seems really messy to me. I've used template engines in the past where you can output the row of a table one at a time and just nest the template method call in your loop. For example, here is some of my old code, using the phpBB2 forum template engine:

```
// Generals
$query = mysql_query("SELECT member_id, member_username, member_rank FROM members WHERE $generals_sql AND $inclan_sql ORDER BY member_rank DESC;");
while ( $members = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
{
    $template->assign_block_vars('generals', array(
        'MEMBER_ID' => $members['member_id'],
        'MEMBER_USERNAME' => format_output($members['member_username']),
        'MEMBER_RANK_TITLE' => $ranks[$members['member_rank']]['title'],
        'MEMBER_GAMES' => get_gameplates($members['member_id']),
        'MEMBER_DSL' => calc_dsl($members['member_id'])
    ));
}
```

.

```
            <!-- BEGIN generals -->
            <tr>
                <td width="25%">
                    <a href="claninfo.php?page=userinfo&view={generals.MEMBER_ID}">{generals.MEMBER_USERNAME}</a>
                </td>
                <td width="35%">
                    {generals.MEMBER_RANK_TITLE}
                </td>
                <td width="30%">
                    {generals.MEMBER_GAMES}
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    {generals.MEMBER_DSL}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- END generals -->
```

Much cleaner, right?

So is there a way to do that in Smarty? A class method I can use to push out variables in a foreach loop one row at a time, instead of all at once?

If not, are there any popular PHP template engines that do have this method? Twig, Blade, Mustache?

If I can't find a template method to do it, maybe I can use array_push() in PHP?

Comment: just use a php loop to build your $smarty->assign('users', array(

or are you talking about the line breaks and spacing in the output code?

Comment: I tried some code to build an array and it's not working. Any suggestions? $races_list = array(); /* inside loop: */ $races_list[$races['race_id']] = array_push($races_list, array('race_name' => get_race_name($races['race_id']))); $smarty->assign('races', $races_list);